# How do I find out if a script is running in an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Basically, I just want something not to run when a page is loaded into an iframe. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (window != window.top) { 
    // the script runs in an iframe
}
```